# Automated test fails, but passes when I try it manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I've already rubber duck tested this a couple of times, and I'm still coming up blank.

EDIT: Posted the wrong chunks of code in there. Have now updated with the correct code and analysis of what I'm seeing. Feeling real smart right now. Thanks, @max, for helping me out.

I refactored a view at the same time as I implemented a new feature, and for some reason, when I start the server and run the test manually, it works just fine, but when I run the automated tests, it fails. I can't figure out why, and Google (or SO) isn't bringing up anything helpful on the topic.

Here's what I'm getting when I run rake test:

```
ERROR["test_profile_display_but_not_skills", UsersProfileTest, 2015-08-03 01:16:05 +0000]                                                                                  
 test_profile_display_but_not_skills#UsersProfileTest (1438564565.47s)                                                                                                     
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass                                                                 
            app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb__2262201056850997174_70092126401660'                                          
            app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3098944701378465381_70092126356440'                                                        
            test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'                                                                               
        app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb__2262201056850997174_70092126401660'                                              
        app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3098944701378465381_70092126356440'                                                            
        test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'                                                                                   

ERROR["test_profile_display_skills", UsersProfileTest, 2015-08-03 01:16:05 +0000]                                                                                          
 test_profile_display_skills#UsersProfileTest (1438564565.48s)                                                                                                             
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass                                                                 
            app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb__2262201056850997174_70092126401660'                                          
            app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3098944701378465381_70092126356440'                                                        
            test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'                                                                               
        app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb__2262201056850997174_70092126401660'                                              
        app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3098944701378465381_70092126356440'                                                            
        test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'
```

I've seen this one enough times now to know that it's trying to call the 'name' method on an object in a class that is nil, and it's often because Rails is trying to call something on an object that isn't defined yet. I thought it might have something to do with the new partial (shared/_user_info.html.erb) that I added to my user_path (users#show) view as part of my refactoring, which I had a little trouble getting to work at first. But a) the partial loads before the page does when I look at what the server spits out in the terminal, and b) I didn't even (seemingly) make updates to that piece of functionality, which is the header partial shared by the application. Also, the partial renders just fine on the other page that it's used on (the home page for the application) and all tests for that page pass, so I don't think it's the partial that's causing the issue.

Here's the integration test that keeps failing (test/integration/users_profile_test.rb):

```
test "profile display but not skills" do
    get user_path(@user) # fail
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.derby_name
end

test "profile display skills" do
    get user_path(@user) # fail
    assert_match @user.skills.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.skills.each do |skill|
        assert_match skill.name, response.body
        assert_match skill.level.to_s, response.body
        assert_match skill.comments, response.body
    end
end
```

In both cases, the failure happens as soon as get user_path(@user) is called. I have no idea why this particular integration test can't call user_path on the fixture I have set for @user; none of my other integration tests are having issues. I'm not sure if it's quite the same as a GET request as far as testing goes, but I'm able to do a PATCH request on user_path(@user) in another integration test (test/integration/users_edit_test.rb):

```
test "successful edit" do
    get edit_user_path(@user) #pass
    log_in_as(@user) #pass
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "Foo Bar", derby_name: "Bar Foo", email: "foo@bar.com" } #pass
    assert_redirected_to @user #pass
end
```

Here's the partial that's causing the issues (I think) (app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb):

```
<aside class="col-md-3">
    <section class="user_info">
        <h1><%= current_user.name %></h1>
        <h1><%= current_user.derby_name %></h1>
        <h2>League Affiliation: [to be developed]</h2>
        <h2>[User type: will display skater, ref, and/or NSO]</h2>
        <span><%= link_to "View my profile", current_user %></span>
        <span>(<%= pluralize(current_user.skills.count, "skill") %>)</span>
    </section>
</aside>
```

This partial is used by the home page (app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb) and the user profile page (app/views/users/show.html.erb). I'm only seeing the issue on the users/show; when I test for the presence of the current_user.name on the home page, it passes. Here's that test:

```
test "logged in user profile view" do
    log_in_as @user
    get root_path
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
end
```

Here's what current_user (used in the partial) is defined in the SessionsHelper as:

```
# Returns the current logged-in user (if any)
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end
```

Again, when starting the server and running the test manually, it's fine, and Rails can figure out that current_user = @user, so it correctly displays the shared/user_info stuff. I have gone over this line-by-line multiple times to make sure I know exactly what it's doing. My understanding of sessions is still a little fuzzy, I think, but I do know that session[:user_id] = user.id based on a method defined in SessionsHelper before current_user:

```
# Logs in the given user
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

Why is the automated test failing while it passes when I do it manually? Is this a common test scenario/error to get? And, obviously, what did I do wrong here and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should really consider splitting your tests up. **Best practice says one assertion per test!** Two maybe if the setup is expensive. Hitting several different URLs in the same test and running assertions is a recipe for disaster. The biggest issue is that the failure messages are going to really meaningless. Instead group into test blocks for each distinct case you are testing.  **Arrange, Act, Assert**

Comment: Your comment made me realize I am looking at the wrong test case. I feel really dumb right now. But I'm not sure why you say the failure messages are going to be meaningless. The error message tells me which file(s) had the errors, and tells me which line the error(s) is on. How is that meaningless?

Comment: Well once your project grows beyond a certain size or if you are several developers on the same project it gets really hard to find why tests are failing or even what behavior or feature the failing tests are supposed to be covering. The context provided by each `test` block is really valuable. This is something we have learned in 40+ years of unit testing and is in almost any book ever written on the subject.

Comment: Also when you structure your tests into a long procedure, you are essentially building test ordering into your test suite. Test ordering is often the cause of flapping tests and can mask bugs which would have been caught if each test is run as its own unit with setup and teardown to assure that there is no state from the previous tests which will affect the current test.

Comment: But anyways if you want debugging advice for this specific issue we need a complete verifiable example - this means your `UsersController`, `users/show.html.erb` and `shared/_user_info.html.erb`

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the post now with the relevant bits of code. I did have another issue with the layout links test earlier, but that's not the issue I'm having here. Thanks for the explanation on the tests, though--I come from an analyst background, so I'm used to grouping tests together like that. I'll break them up from now on.

Comment: The issue is most likely that you need to check if there is a current_user in your show view. like: `render partial: 'shared/user_info' if current_user`. The alternative is to check if current_user is nil in your partial. That would explain why the test when you are logged in passes while the other tests where current user is nil fail.

Comment: Got it--had to use my log_in_as helper to log in the test fixture. I also added that 'render partial: "shared/user_info" if current_user' logic to the view to help prevent further errors. Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions. I really appreciate it!